# how to show that a group of order $p^k$ has subgroups of order $p^i$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am trying to use this fact in another proof, and I would like to make sure what I'm doing is correct first. Basically, I have a group, $G$ of order $p^k$, and I would like to show that there exist subgroups with order $p^i$ for all $i \leq k$.  Here is what I have so far.

By Cauchy's Theorem, since $p^i$ divides $p^k$ for all $i \in \{1,2,...,k\}$, this means there is an element of order $p^i$. Thus, I can make a subgroup generated by this element, and it will also have order $p^i$ (which is a simple proof).

My issue with this is that it implies that $G$ is cyclic since there is an element of order $p^k$ by Cauchy. I have tried looking things up in several ways to try to disprove that, but I haven't found any good examples by googling. By the definition of a cyclic group, this would mean that $G$ is abelian too, and I am pretty sure that is not always the case? I think my understanding of Cauchy's theorem and cyclic groups in general must be wrong, but I'm not sure where I'm getting lost. I know that all groups of prime order are cyclic, but is that the case with groups of order of $p$ to some power?

Any tips/hints would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Not all $p$-groups are cyclic. Indeed not all $p$-groups are Abelian.

Comment: You might want to consider the group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$. which has order $2^2$, but no element of order $2^2$; that suggests you're misapplying Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem only promises the existence of an element of order $p$ precisely. Higher order elements need not exist.

Comment: To prove the existence of such a subgroup you apply Cauchy to the center of $G$ (known to be non-trivial). Then form the quotient (of order $p^{k-1}$) and apply a suitable the induction hypotesis.

Comment: Ah okay!  I tried induction before, but I didn't get the whole way through.  Dumb question, but how did you know to apply it to the center of G? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Any subgroup of the center is normal. And normality is needed to form the quotient group.

Comment: Ah makes sense!  Thank you! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Good. Now work a bit on making all the pieces of the puzzle fit together. Then I want to encourage you to post the end result as an answer. That way A) you will get feedback on any lingering unclear steps, and B) the question will be removed from the queue of unanswered questions :-)

Comment: I will do!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class equation to show $G$ has a non-trivial center $Z$.  Raise a non-identity element of $Z$ to a power such that the result $g\in Z$ has order $p$.  Then $G/<g>$ is a smaller p-group and has subgroups of all smaller powers of $p$ by induction.  Their pre-images provide the needed subgroups of $G$.

Note that the same proof works with "subgroup" replaced by "normal subgroup" throughout.  Thus $G$ also has a normal subgroup of order $p^i$.